# How to fix "Failed to create a room" while trying to authenticate on?

Tags: api, cisco, webex

I am starting a basic Cisco API training at developer.cisco.com. While trying to authenticate the Webex API to advance in the exercise. I enter:

```
curl https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages -X POST -H "Authorization:Bearer YW ... 46" --data "toPersonEmail=mauricio9991@gmail.com" --data "text=Hi%20from%20DevNet"
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
{"message":"Failed to create room.","errors":[{"description":"Failed to create room."}],"trackingId":"ROUTER_5D6FA925-CB89-01BB-5BBD-C02E340A5BBD"}
```

I am learning about coding and API.

I am not a developer. I am studying CCNA and I am starting to learn about API for networking. Already created a Webex teams account.

It is supose to display some result like this:

```
  "id":"Y2l...mNh",
   "roomId":"Y2l...WMy",
   "toPersonEmail":"someone@cisco.com",
   "roomType":"direct",
   "text":"Hi from DevNet",
   "personId":"Y2l...ODc",
   "personEmail":"labs@chatbot.land",
   "created":"2018-12-13T23:32:43.377Z"
```

Comment: Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens on your end, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webex-training-center-api

You can use this api which I have designed for webex-training-center.